# Hide action name in URL ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Have `UsersController` and `Details` action has id (string) parameter of user in system identity.

How can I create MapRoute, to see this :

```
http://localhost:54719/Users/bade9105-adfe-46b3-b0db-68f3f6e0dd13
```

instead of :

```
http://localhost:54719/Users/Details/bade9105-adfe-46b3-b0db-68f3f6e0dd13
```

and do an automatic redirection, not just access without entering the controller name.

Comment: Your desired url **is** showing the controller name (did you mean you want to hide the action name?)

Comment: Are you using asp.net mvc 5?

Comment: I think you need to hide action name instead of controller (the controller name is `Users`). If you using MVC 5, `RouteAttribute` with URL can be used instead.

Comment: 1. yes.
2. yes.

Comment: did you ever solve your problem? thinking about posting an answer but interested to see if you already have one

Answer (score 0):

`Detail` is not your controller's name, it's an action name
try this: 
(add to your `RoutingConfig.cs`)

```
  routes.MapRoute(
  name: "userdetail",
  url: "Users/{userid}",
  defaults: new
  {
      controller = MVC.Users.Name,
      action = MVC.Users.ActionNames.showuserdetail,
      userid = UrlParameter.Optional
  },
  namespaces: new[] { string.Format("{0}.Controllers", 
 typeof(RoutingConfig).Namespace) }
 );
```

(showuserdetail is your action name)

you need to use routing to do what you want.